# Beginner question regarding batteries' voltage/amperage

Tags: batteries

I want to use two batteries rated 6v, 4A with a 9v,1A device. I figured that connecting the batteries in parallel would give 12v and connecting a 3ohm resistor in series with the device would give the device 9v(law of potential dividers). Now, to get the required current, do I connect a resistor(~8 ohm) in parallel to the device? Would that do the trick?

Also, how do I set up the circuit to charge these batteries up?

Comment: often when someone rates their device they are rating the **maximum** current their device will draw.

Comment: but I think according to stevenvh's answer, if I use voltage regulators, I won't have to bother about the current; am I right?

Comment: they voltage regulator will have a current limit as well that you will need to make sure you dont exceed.

Comment: I am trying to help with understanding. In electronics we control voltage in almost all applications. If they say their device is rated to 9V then it will pull the current it needs. If it says it will pull 1A it will pull 1A. There is no need for you to handle this. If it is electronics of any sort the current draw probably varies a large amount and a series resistor is a poor method for regulation.

Answer (score 10):

To get 12V you have to put them **in series**. This gives you 12V @ 4A. Placing them **in parallel** would give you double the current, i.e. 6V @ 8A. This is a bit tricky, however, because voltages of the two batteries have to be exact the same, otherwise a large current will run from one battery to the other. As safety measure you place small resistors in series with each battery.

So you place them in series. A series resistor to get a defined lower voltage is **never a good idea**, because the voltage drop over the resistor will vary with the load. Use a voltage regulator, like [LM7809](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/LM/LM7809.pdf) or [LM317](http://www.national.com/profile/snip.cgi/openDS=LM317). The former will give you a fixed 9V, the latter is adjustable. This converts the 12V in to 9V out. If you connect the 9V, 1A device you'll have this 1A current automatically.

[image: typical application]

Comment: @stevenvh- Thanks. Would l7805 do? Hey and also could you please explain how I should charge these batteries(I'll do this most probably using solar).

Comment: 78L05 would give you 5 V out, not 9 V.

Comment: @gomek - endolith mentions the 78**L**05. Not only will this give you 5V, it the "L" version will also limit the output current to 100mA. So you don't want the 78L09, you want the 7809!

Comment: @gomek - what kind of battery is this? Lead-acid?

Comment: @stevenvh- yes it's lead acid

Comment: @gomek - I haven't used lead-acid in ages, but IIRC charge for 14 hours at 2.3V per cell (13.8V if you place both batteries in series), current limited to 10% of nominal capacity, here 400mA. But I'd like to see these numbers confirmed by an expert!

Comment: @gomek (http://www.datasheetcatalog.org/datasheets2/52/529144_1.pdf) shows a circuit for an adjustable 7-30V output regulator using the 7805 (bottom of page 24)

Comment: You will also need to cool the 7809 to get the full 1A.

Comment: Not to thread hijack, but can you put 2 matched 78XX in parallel to double current?

Comment: @William - They're never perfectly matched, and even a small voltage difference in the low impedance output will cause a large current flow from one to the other. The datasheet shows an application where you can increase current with an external transistor.

Answer (score 0):

Correct about voltages math (except your typo in batteries should be in series). For most practical loads it will work. In first approximation, you are correct thinking that device is equivalent to resistor of 9 ohm.

Not correct, if you will add parallel resistor 8 ohm. You will have to recalculate the upper part of potentiometer. Go through formula for parallel resistors value, put value into potentiometer folmula or ohms law, see what current is there.

When it can be not good at all:
The unknown part is if the equivalent resistor is still 9 ohm at 9.001v and 8.999v. If it is not (say it is designed to consume constant power, instead of constant voltage or current), for example there is small decrease in equivalent resistance value with increase of voltage. Then consequently you have an oscillator.

Answer (score 0):

While a LDO like the 7809 can work, its is highly inefficient (75% at most). You are connecting two batteries in series to raise the voltage, then dropping it down using a linear regulator. At 1 Amp, that's 12v - 9v * 1A or 3v * 1A = 3 Watts of power wasted, in heat. You will need to add a heatsink to the regulator. And as the batteries drain, the input voltage will go down, and you will not have the 2v drop out voltage needed to properly regulate at 9v.

Instead, you should use a step up (Boost) switching regulator. Very little components needed, no heat issues, and efficiency at 80 to 95%. And you only need one battery, not both.

Typical setup:
[image: enter link description here]
<sub>(source: [eleccircuit.com](http://www.eleccircuit.com/wp-content/uploads/2007/09/lm2577-12-circuit.gif))</sub>